# Where to store session data in a multi-tenant .Net web platform without using session objects?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, session-cookies, formsauthenticationticket

We have all see the overuse and misuse of session objects through web-based .Net applications.

In moving away from this practice there are options like SOSS and other server-based options to store this data.

In trying to keep the architecture more simple, I have become a fan of creating a user object and storing the serialized version in `FormsAuthenticationTicket.UserData`.

This requires a bit of extra overhead on every page load but workable.  User ID's are maintained as a GUID so no "guessing" if someone looks at their cookie, plus it can be encrypted.

Other options?

Comment: [This post](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/) has some good ideas about possible alternatives to session state. Your cookie idea could work if the amount of data is small, but keep in mind that cookies are transferred on *every* request (including images, css, and js files), so they can make your bandwidth usage skyrocket if you are not careful. That said, are you referring to user session data, or [per-tenant global settings](http://benfoster.io/blog/asp-net-5-multitenancy)?

Comment: Right, I believe the strategy is to populate the cookie on `PageUnload` then on `PageLoad` (essentially) read from the cookie to re-populate screen details.  Not storing images, CSS, JS in the cookie.

Comment: `Not storing images, CSS, JS in the cookie.` - No, that is not what I meant. *Any* image, CSS, or JS file referenced from your page will produce another request to your server from the browser. In each of those requests, your cookie will be transmitted from client to server. So, if your cookie size is 1KB and you have 10 images, 5 CSS files, and 5 JS files on the page, you will actually be sending 21KB of data (1KB for each request including the page) across the network on page load for your 1KB cookie.